# convert pdo code of Foreach loop to mysqli

Tags: php

```
<?php
  echo "<select name= 'sales' value=''>Sales Person Name</option>";
  echo "<option value = 'Select Sales Person' selected>Select Sales Person</option>";
{
    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row){
    echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>"; 
}
    echo "</select>";
}
echo "<br>";
?>
```

I am trying to convert my PDO code to MySql in foreach loop but i did not know how to do it , and i am beginner to PHP, please help me to how to do it.

Comment: why would u want to convert pdo to mysql? mysql is decaprecated and u shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "yourqueryhere";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name= 'sales' value=''>Sales Person Name</option>";
echo "<option value = 'Select Sales Person' selected>Select Sales Person</option>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=$row['id']>$row['name']</option>";
}

$conn->close();
```